# What killed my process?

Tags: linux, process, kill, redhat-enterprise-linux

Been having a problem with application that keeps getting killed. This is running a RHEL5 server.  We ran strace against the process and at the end of the trace file I get a bunch of *+++ killed by SIGKILL +++* messages.  SIGKILL can't be caught so I'm trying to find a way to track down why the process is getting killed.

I tried using some recommendations from Red Hat such as

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S kill
```

which didn't seem to work.  I didn't see any entries for kill in the audit.log.

Another recommendation from Red Hat was to use systemtap.  I installed it via yum and tried to run stap with the sigmon.stp script that was provided.  The sigmon.stp is on this page: [Sigmon.stp](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/sigmon.stp)
I used the command provided in the comments section and here is the output:

```
# stap sigmon.stp -x 12647 SIGKILL -v
Pass 1: parsed user script and 85 library script(s) using 146868virt/23716res/3024shr/21404data kb, in 110usr/10sys/116real ms.
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'kernel' at /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/signal.stp:60:37
        source: probe __signal.send.send_sigqueue = kernel.function("send_sigqueue")
                                                    ^
semantic error: missing x86_64 kernel/module debuginfo under '/lib/modules/2.6.18-308.13.1.el5/build'
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier '__signal' at :39:21
        source: probe signal.send = __signal.send.send_sigqueue,
                                    ^
semantic error: no match
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'signal' at sigmon.stp:30:7
        source: probe signal.send 
                      ^
Pass 2: analyzed script: 1 probe(s), 0 function(s), 0 embed(s), 0 global(s) using 150348virt/28920res/4696shr/24884data kb, in 30usr/40sys/81real ms.
Pass 2: analysis failed.  Try again with another '--vp 01' option.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install kernel-2.6.18-308.13.1.el5.x86_64
```

Has anyone had luck using the stap command?  Is there another way I can find out what's killing my process?

Comment: Does your process use a LOT of memory? The kernel will kill processes using too much memory if they start affecting the performance of the system.

Comment: "What killed my process?" -> "killed by SIGKILL"

Comment: Ah, but the intended question is probably "which program dispatched the sigkill?"

Comment: Any clues in the system logs?

Comment: The process is java based, so yes it uses a fair amount of memory. We have bumped up the memory and the issue remains.  I've read about oom killer, think I'll try disabling the oom killer tomorrow to see if I can rule that out. But I wasn't able to find any trace of oom killer in the logs. And yes to Hennes, I am looking to narrow down who dispatched the sigkill.

Comment: Try to track the memory usage of your running app, and generate a report. There is probably a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

SystemTap looks like it can't find the debug symbols for your kernel. Have you installed the required kernel debug packages for the kernel you are running? The SystemTap guide says:

> To deploy SystemTap, you need to install the SystemTap packages along with the corresponding set of -devel, -debuginfo and -debuginfo-common packages for your kernel. If your system has multiple kernels installed, and you wish to use SystemTap on more than one kernel kernel, you will need to install the -devel and -debuginfo packages for each of those kernel versions.